# C++ How to create an array (vtable) of class methods?

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, emulation

I am making an emulator in c++ and currently implementing the CPU. The CPU class' fetch-decode-execute cycle needs to read in an opcode and then call an appropriate method on the class to execute the next instruction.

I can easily implement this with a `switch` statement. However I feel (I'm not very familiar with c++ optimizations) it will be more efficient to have an array defined on the CPU class which maps opcodes to the correct methods.

So, the fetch-decode-execute cycle could look something like this:

```
while (true) {
  uint8_t opcode = fetch();
  vtable[opcode]();
}
```

How can I define such an array in (modern) C++? What's the type? How do I initialize it in the header file?

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<void()>> vtable;` or `std::map<uint8_t, std::function<void()>> vtable;`  Since the range is `uint8_t` which is relatively small, the `vector` will probably work best.

Comment: @Eljay any reason to use `std::vector` over a plain old array?

Comment: I'd use a `std::vector`, but could be convinced to use a `std::array`.  I would not use a C-style array.